# Conflict creating table with Index and Primary Key

Tags: oracle

I'm a veteran SQL Server dev, recently moved to a project requiring Oracle and I'm confused by the error [ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key] I'm getting on Oracle 11.

I'm attempting to create a reference table, with an index and a primary key.
However, getting errors that my column Partner_ID is already declared.  I know I'm missing something simple, but the docs and other sources I've viewed here have not given me a clue. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

```
ALTER TABLE REF_PARTNER
DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;

DROP TABLE REF_PARTNER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE REF_PARTNER
(
  PARTNER_ID               NUMBER(10)  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  GLOBAL_APPID             VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)      NOT NULL,
  FRIENDLY_NAME            VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)      NOT NULL,
  CREATE_DTS               DATE,
  MODIFIED_DTS             DATE,
  LAST_MODIFIED_USER       VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE DATA_1
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    5
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          1M
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE PARTNER_SEQ';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;

CREATE SEQUENCE PARTNER_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1     NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE CACHE 200;


--CREATE UNIQUE INDEX REF_PARTNER_IDX ON REF_PARTNER
--(PARTNER_ID)
--LOGGING
--TABLESPACE INDEX_1
--PCTFREE    10
--INITRANS   2
--MAXTRANS   255
--STORAGE    (
--            INITIAL          64K
--            NEXT             64K
--            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
--            MINEXTENTS       1
--            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
--            PCTINCREASE      0
--            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
--           );

--ALTER TABLE REF_PARTNER ADD (
--  CONSTRAINT REF_PARTNER_PK
--  PRIMARY KEY
--  (PARTNER_ID)
--  USING INDEX REF_PARTNER_PK
--  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A assume the error you get is

```
ORA-01408: such column list already indexed.
```

This is because you create the table with partner_id as the primary key. This automatically creates a unique index on partner_id. 
There is no need to create a unique key on partner_id after you declared it to be the primary key.

Comment: Thank you, thought I had read primary keys didn't create indexes.